# RPCNFSDCOUNT is ignored on Ubuntu Server 22.04.1

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

I'm trying to increase the thread count of nfsd by editing `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` file. I set up `RPCNFSDCOUNT=48` but after reboot, nfsd thread count is still Ubuntu default which is 8.

```
root@nfs-server2:~# ps ax | grep nfsd
   2589 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/nfsdcld
   2596 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
   2597 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
   2598 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
   2599 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
   2600 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
   2601 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
   2602 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
   2603 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
   2790 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto nfsd
```

Only changing thread count by hand is working.

```
root@nfs-server2:~# rpc.nfsd 48
root@nfs-server2:~# ps ax | grep "\[nfsd\]" | wc -l
48
```

But this is not reboot-proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make the changes stick by changing the threads in **/etc/nfs.conf.d/local.conf**

```
[nfsd]
vers2 = n
vers3 = n
threads = 16

[mountd]
manage-gids = 1
```

And then restarting **nfs-server**

```
sudo systemctl restart nfs-server.service
```

Answer (score 1):

The /etc/default/nfs-kernel-server is not used in ubuntu 22 https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-nfs